# Why is django not making migrations for my models

Tags: python, django, mysql-python, django-migrations, pythonanywhere

I uploaded my django app to pythonanywhere and it worked with sqlite database,
but on switching to mysql it doesnt make migrations but it migrates the admin tables when i rum `python manage.py migrate`

this is my settings app

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

import environ
env = environ.Env(
    DEBUG=(bool, False)
)
environ.Env.read_env()

DEBUG = env('DEBUG')
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Raises django's ImproperlyConfigured exception if SECRET_KEY not in os.environ
SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')

if DEBUG:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

else:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
        '*',
    ]



INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main',
    'projects',
    'services',

    'crispy_forms',
    'crispy_bootstrap5',
    # should be at bottom
    'django_cleanup.apps.CleanupConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'vectorapp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'vectorapp.wsgi.application'


if not DEBUG:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': os.getenv("DB_ENGINE"),
            'NAME': os.getenv("DB_NAME"),
            'USER': os.getenv("DB_USER"),
            'PASSWORD': os.getenv("DB_PASSWORD"),
            'HOST': os.getenv("DB_HOST"),
            # 'PORT': os.getenv("DB_PORT"),
            "OPTIONS": {
                'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES', innodb_strict_mode=1",
                'charset': 'utf8mb4',
                "autocommit": True,
            }
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
        }
    }


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


CRISPY_ALLOWED_TEMPLATE_PACKS = "bootstrap5"
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = "bootstrap5"


STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

# STATIC_ROOT = 'static_root'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/media/')


DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'


if not DEBUG:
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'backend.storage.AzureMediaStorage'
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'backend.storage.AzureStaticStorage'
    SECRET_KEY = env("SECRET_KEY")
    AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME = env("AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME")
    AZURE_CONNECTION_STRING = env("AZURE_CONNECTION_STRING")
    AZURE_ACCOUNT_KEY = env("AZURE_ACCOUNT_KEY")
    AZURE_URL_EXPIRATION_SECS = int(env("AZURE_URL_EXPIRATION_SECS"))
    # custom
    AZURE_MEDIA_CONTAINER = env("AZURE_MEDIA_CONTAINER")
    AZURE_STATIC_CONTAINER = env("AZURE_STATIC_CONTAINER")
```

what am i doing wrong here?
i have used various databases And still it says no changes detected when i try to migrate

Comment: Changing the database setting will *not* change the migrations, since these migrations are made in a "dialict-invariant style".

Comment: try replacing sqlite with msql in datatbases

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [Django Migration Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/#the-commands):

> The migration files for each app live in a “migrations” directory inside of that app, and are designed to be committed to, and distributed as part of, its codebase. You should be making them once on your development machine and then running the same migrations on your colleagues’ machines, your staging machines, and eventually your production machines.

So it looks like what you describe is normal, because you have already committed the migrations along with the code to the server. You can run

```
python manage.py showmigrations
```

in a shell to see what has been applied